# SCAN verification error during 11gr2 installation

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, oracle-grid-control

[image]

Hi All, 
I am getting the following warning when installing RAC DB (11.2.0.4). Does any one has idea what could be the reason? I have tried to search from Metalink but no help. Can I proceed with the warning? What will be the impact if I ignore the warning and proceed?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What version of windows (version and 32/64-bit) are you on?

Comment: It's 64 bit ( Win 2012 Standard Edition).